# jquery and ajax. How to retrieve data for this field and return to right checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am stuck with some coding.
This is my issue. I have no problem submitting the data to the database varchar field as json using php but how do I retrieve and have the right checkboxes being checked using jquery.
Here are the checkboxes and then below that is the data submitted to the database field as json.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="referto[]" value="1"/>Infection Control
<input type="checkbox" name="referto[]" value="2"/>Medical
<input type="checkbox" name="referto[]" value="3"/>Nursing Administration
<input type="checkbox" name="referto[]" value="4"/>Personnel
<input type="checkbox" name="referto[]" value="5"/>Quality Committee
<input type="checkbox" name="referto[]" value="6"/>Risk and Safety
<input type="checkbox" name="referto[]" value="7"/>EAP
<input type="checkbox" name="referto[]" value="8"/>Other
```

Json data from the referto field

```
["1","3","6","7"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would account for unchecking boxes as well.

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON( '["1","3","6","7"]' );

 $.each($("input[name='referto[]']"), function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(this).prop('checked', data.indexOf(value) !==  -1);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data = jQuery.parseJSON( '["1","3","6","7"]' );
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {

  $('input[name="referto[]"][value="'+obj+'"]').prop('checked', true);

});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tu8wqekc/) is jsfiddle demo.